# Change CSS when #section is reached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to rotate icon (**class="user-icon"**) with CSS if **#section2** is reached when scrolling.

```
    <ol class="curtains"> 
  <li id="section-1" class="cover" ">
    <section class="center-block">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="col1-1 centered">

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
  <!--SECTION BACKGROUND IMAGES ARE SET IN CSS IN /CSS/STYLES.CSS-->
  <li id="section-2" class="cover" style="background-color:#e74c3c">
    <section class="center-block">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix"> 
        <span class="user-icon></span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>       
</ol>
```

I have tried thid code but it dosent work :

```
var targetOffset = $("#section-2").offset().top; 
var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) { 
        $('.user-icon').css({
            "-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            transform: rotate(45deg);
         "});
    } else { 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything* or do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: I have tried thid code but it dosent work : 

var targetOffset = $("#section-2").offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        $('.user-icon').css({"-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);"}); 
    } else {
      
    }
});

Comment: That's invalid use of the `.css()` function. Read http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp

Comment: I used this code  it works ! but user-icon become red even the section-2 is not reached :

<script>  
    var $jq1122 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

   $jq1122 (window).scroll(function () {

   if ($jq1122 (window).scrollTop() + $jq1122 (window).height() > $jq1122 ('#section-2').offset().top) {
    $jq1122 (".ro").css("color", "red");
    } else {
     
   }
  });

  </script>